# Excel VBA swapping cells if value is an array

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, for-loop, vba

Abigaylebury    South Carolina

Abigaylebury    South Carolina

South Carolina  Abigaylebury

*idea is to automatically swap wrongly placed states with home towns .i.e south caroline & abigaylebury

i've got 5001 rows and trying to access in particular two columns (Home town, Home state). 
I am trying to write a vba script that swaps the home town and home state values, if i have a home state value wrongly placed in the home town column . I've tried to do this by having an array that references a range of all 50 states inside the worksheet and should be checked against in the if statement.

However i keep getting mismatch, define application defined or object defined error. novice errors im sure.

this is my attempt:

```
Dim states() As String 
states = Range("N1:N50").Value 
Dim x As Long 
Dim y As Long 

'go through rows in the d column
For x = 1 To 5001
    'Range("D" & x).Select

        'for loop for array and if statement
            For y = 1 To 50

            states() = Cells(y, n)

                    If y <= 1 Then

            'second for loop

                    Var = Cells(2, 4)
                    Cells(2, 4) = Cells(2, 5)
                    Cells(2, 5) = Var

                   End If

            Next y 'go to next 1..50            
Next x
```

Comment: In `states() = Cells(y, n)` there is no `n` variable defined in your program. Could that be the source of your error?

Comment: You can simply use a Vlookup function. Can you paste the screenshot of data in your post.

Comment: Also, IIRC, you need to correctly ReDim your `states` array before you assign a range of values to it.

Comment: the first error is declaring your array `As String`. to absorb range values into arrays like that, it *must* be: `Dim states() As Variant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that I think might help you. Suppose my sheet is set up as follows:

```
      A     B     C     D            E           ...     N
1                       Home State   Home Town           States
2                       KS           Townsville          AL
3                       ME           Bar Harbor          AK
4                       CO           Boulder             AR
5     etc...
```

I can then use the following to check if any entry in `Home Town` is actually a state name and, if so, swap that value with the `Home State`.

```
Dim states As Variant

Sub CheckHomeTown()
    Dim rw As Long, temp As Variant
    states = Range("N2:N52")               //Assign states to module level variable 'states'

    For rw = 2 To 5001                     //Loop through all 'Home Town` entries...
        If IsState(Cells(rw, 5)) Then      //If 'Home Town' is actually a state then swap...
            temp = Cells(rw, 4)
            Cells(rw, 4) = Cells(rw, 5)
            Cells(rw, 5) = temp
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub

Function IsState(val As Range) As Boolean
    Dim match As Boolean        
    match = False

    For Index = 1 To UBound(states)
        If val = states(Index, 1) Then
            match = True
        End If
    Next Index

    IsState = match
End Function
```